# Android Mysql Connection not working

Tags: android, mysql

I have recently updated my AVD and Eclipse ADT. After the update my android project is not running properly.

The part that isn't working properly is my connection to mysql data base.

My code:

```
String data= "";

String database(){

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/sakila","root","warlock");
    PreparedStatement stmt= conn.prepareStatement("Select * from actor");

    ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery();
    int i=0;

    while(res.next() && i <9)
    { 
        data=data+res.getString("actor_id") + "   " + res.getString("first_name") + "&";
        System.out.println(data);
        i++;
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e); }
TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

tv.setText(data);
```

Before the update it worked fined. I didn't have to connect via php. What could be wrong in this? I did the update today in the morning. 5:30 IST

Comment: Is that code work with java console application?

Comment: no i wrote it to check if i could get to debug, as it gave Output when it worked on LogCat or Console, i dont remember which one exactly

Answer (score 0):

You must use SQLite not mysql. [Information about SQLite + Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Comment: I dont wanna use a local database storage facility !! I want to use a central server based facility. I would've used it if my application needed to have only local database

Answer (score 0):

Add internet permission in your app Manifest File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Have done that too...it was working before as I said :) if i hadnt it wouldnt work in first place